# Error on the len() funtion for a palindrome project

Tags: python, error-handling, project

I'm on chapter 2 of the book Impractical Python Projects and I'm working on the code that is supposed to go through a dictionary list, find the palindromes in the list, and print them out in a new list. Here's the code.

```
import load_dictionary

word_list= load_dictionary.load('2of4brif.txt')
pali_list= []

for word in word_list:
    if len(word) > 1 and word == word[::-1]:
        pali_list.append(word)

print("\nNumber of palindromes found = {}\n".format(len(pali_list)))
print(*pali_list, sep='\n')
```

I'm having problems wit the if statement with the len() function. When I try to run the code it keeps returning this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

I tried changing the name 'word' to something else, thinking that maybe it was the built-in funtion that was being talked about, but the result is the same for each word or letter that I tried to use

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
2of4brif.txt is a downloaded list of words provided for the project to be used for the search for palindromes.

Here's the code in load_dictionary:

[load_dictionary.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPh0r.png)

Comment: What does 2of4brif.txt look like? What is *load_dictionary*?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, code works fine (other than missing input data).

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error? `len` appears in multiple places in your code.  And what are the actual contents of `word_list` (as opposed to what you *expect* them to be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load_dictionary is missing a parentheses at the lower case method. The word_list contains only the .lower built in method, not the actual words, since without the parentheses the function doesn't get called, it actually means the function itself.

```
def load(file): 
    try: 
        with open(file) as in_file: 
            loaded_txt = in_file.read().strip().split('\n') 
            loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt] #Here
            return loaded_txt

    except IOError as e:
        print("{}\nError opening {}. Terminating program.".format(e, file),
            file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is just a list of words (one per line) then all you need is:

```
pali_list = []

def normalise(s: str) -> str:
    return s.strip().lower()

def ispalindrome(s: str) -> bool:
    return len(s) > 1 and s == s[::-1]

with open("2of4brif.txt") as words:
    for word in map(normalise, words):
        if ispalindrome(word):
            pali_list.append(word)

print(f"\nNumber of palindromes found = {len(pali_list)}\n")
print(*pali_list, sep="\n")
```